# How to center a form horizontally and vertically

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have tried 5 different ways and the form will not center vertically so that its in the middle of the page no matter what I do. What am I doing wrong?

```
<ion-content no-bounce padding>
  <ion-list no-lines>
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin()" novalidate>

      <div class="loginForm">
        <ion-item>
          <p style="text-align: center">
            <img class="center-block text-center" src="">
          </p>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
          <ion-input formControlName="email" type="email" id="email"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
          <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password" id="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <button ion-button full color="primary" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Login</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

scss

```
.loginForm{
  display: flex!important;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
  justify-content: center!important;
}
```

I've also tried it like this

```
.loginForm{ 
   height: 100%;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and like this

```
.loginForm {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with viewport units?
https://plnkr.co/edit/8BXmvgXl0GRh4ED2doYc?p=preview

Comment: Of course, you have to calculate the percentajes. They must be according the content size (i.e. if the button size is the 80% of the visible screen, left will be 10vh. you can use 'calc' at scss)

Comment: check http://plnkr.co/edit/kL2OuP?p=preview

Comment: Thank you it works. Still dont understand why the other ways didnt work.